# Matlab File Reading

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a file that has numerous data points, all formatted like XX.XXX  The numbers are strung together continuously.

How do I separate all the numbers into individual values?

I tried reading from the file with '%5.3d' and '%5.3f' but neither of them worked.  Likewise, '%6s' did not work.

Example Input:

```
75.91425.43937.55492.55874.43839.51519.59935.11762.33178.14914.81569.43037.90083.32590.492
70.45060.24634.07148.20638.34348.88881.90070.37655.06531.76382.54791.43659.88274.56288.827
87.28590.39641.39551.67340.39870.613
```

Desired Output:

```
75.914
25.439
37.554
92.558
etc.
```

I have tried:

```
fscanf(Fid,'%6.3f',[3 inf]);
fscanf(Fid,'%5.3f',[3 inf]);
fscanf(Fid,'%5.3f',[3 inf]);
fscanf(Fid,['%2d' char('.') '%3d'], [6 inf]);
```

Comment: No.  The returned matrix from fscanf is ''

Comment: I would suggest editting your question with a data sample, code sample that you use for reading, exactly what you expect to get, and what you are currently getting. I am not too good friends with Matlab, but expanding question would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming every element is 6 characters you could do the following since fscanf isn't working.  Note: I saved your sample into "numData.txt"

EDIT: This is much better.

```
fid = fopen('numData.txt','r');
numArray = textscan(fid,'%6.3f',inf);
```

gives

```
numArray =

   75.9140
   25.4390
   37.5540
   ... etc
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me either. I am very confused as to why there would be any issue.  All the syntax seems correct.

Comment: @NathanTornquist I have no idea why that doesn't work.  I just pasted your sample into a text file and no issues.  Maybe there is something in your data file that does not conform to your example.  Are you getting errors when you try the above code or is the resulting array just empty?  Also I would check your data file to see if there are any line feeds, spaces, etc. That break the pattern.